# DTW algorithm: simple implementation - Verification

Tags: algorithm, image-recognition, formal-verification, dtw

I have tried to make a simple implementation of the DTW algorithm in C,without using any substantial optimization techniques. I am trying to use this implementation for some simple sketch recognition, which is to say finding the k closest neighbors of a given sketch from within a set. I have gotten some results that seem weird to me and I  would like to know of this is because of my dtw implementation. I need someone to verify my algorithm.

As I said,  I am trying to find the k closest neighbors, so the only 'optimization' I have implemented to make calculations faster is that if the minimum cost of a given line calculated is at any point greater than the maximum distance between the k sketches currently considered as the closest neighbors, I stop calculating and return +inf.

Here is the corresponding algorithm:

```
(returnValue totalCost) dtw(sketch1, sketch2, curMaxDist){
   distMatrix = 'empty matrix of size (sketch.size) x (sketch2.size)'
   totalCostMatrix = 'empty matrix of size (sketch1.size) x (sketch2.size)'
   for(i = 0 to sketch1.size - 1){
       for(j = 0 to sketch2.size - 1){ 
          distMatrix[i][j] = euclidianDistance(sketch1.point[i], sketch2.point[j])
          totalCostMatrix[i][j] = +inf
       }
    }
   //I am forcing the first points of each sketch to correspond to one 
   // and continue applying the algorithm from the next points.

   for(i = 1 to sketch1.size - 1){
      curMinDist = +inf
      for(j = 1 to sketch2.size - 1){
           totalCostMatrix[i][j] = min(totalCostMatrix[i-1][j-1],
                                       totalCostMatrix[i-1][j],             
                                       totalCostMatrix[i][j-1]) + distMatrix[i][j]
           if(totalCostMatrix[i][j] < curMinDist)
               curMinDist = totalCostMatrix[i][j]
      }  
      if(curMinDist > curMaxDist)
           return +inf
   }

   return totalCostMatrix[sketch1.size - 1][sketch2.size - 1]
}
```

I am sure there is nothind wrong with the implementation as far as the syntax, C language etc is concerned since I have checked that and I always get the expectes result. I was just wandering if there is something wrong with the reasoning behind the algorithm. I am asking because it is a really well known algorithm and a really simple implementation so maybe it is easy for someone to spot an error there.

Comment: I don't see anything at a first glance, your description seems to match [this article's](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.167.600&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (also only glanced at it). Since you're not using windowing constraints, maybe that's why you get weird results?

Comment: The algorithm seems to be correct finally. It was probably because of the sketches themselves (hand drawn using a mousepad on a certain plateform) and the lack of other optimization methods that probably resulted in some confusing matches. Thanks a lot.